# OpenGL Coplanar Surfaces

Tags: opengl

In my OpenGL problem set, I have drawn a particular polygon and with the mouse selection, I want to draw a square from the place I have selected. The square drawn gets updated rapidly with my change in mouse motion and finally should be affixed to the end point where I release the mouse button.

In my mouse motion routine, I tried doing the `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` and called a `drawSquare` function that I have written. The `glClear` ensures that I have only a unique square drawn and not a blotch of previous images appearing. However, this clearing also clears my initial polygon that I had drawn.

Please advice on how to make sure I have this new square (from mouse) on top of my existing polygon.

**P.S :** I tried drawing the underlying polygon on the backbuffer and the square on the front, but the `glutSwapBuffers()` created havoc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 4):

Like many others you seem to mistake OpenGL for a scene managment API, which is plain wrong. OpenGL does nothing else than draw something to the screen. After it's drawn OpenGL completely forgets about the polygon. So what this means is, that you have to draw everything you want to be shown every frame (often after clearing the framebuffer).

So clear the framebuffer, draw your polygon and draw your square. Once the square position (or anything else) changes, clear the framebuffer again, draw the polygon and draw your square. That's the way it works.

And also you should of course not draw anything in the mouse routine, let aside call `glClear`, which results in exactly the kind of rubbish you're experiencing. Instead update your scene and request the window to redraw itself, which in turn draws the whole scene in the display method:

```
mouseFunc()
{
    updateSquare();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


displayFunc()
{
    glClear(...);
    drawPolygon();
    drawSquare();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

And of course by all means don't draw to the front buffer when using double buffering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I would like to clarify that the initial polygon that I am drawing is from an exhaustive mathematical analysis of a huge matrix and thus, it takes quite a while to draw the first polygon.

So, using glutPostRedisplay() seems to delay the drawing by a couple of seconds.

Comment: @user1058100 In this case, your design is just wrong. Don't interleave the complicated computation of the polygon with its drawing. Just compute its vertices once using the exhaustive mathematical analysis and then just draw these vertices as a polygon each time it needs to be drawn. Again, don't misuse OpenGL for managing your scene or these are exactly the problems you will be facing.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I will work on my design again.
I have one more question,
In your sequence of drawPolygon() and drawSquare(), how will glutFlush() affect the scenario instead of glutSwapBuffers. I still don't understand how coplanar surfaces are handled by OpenGL.

Thanks for your patience

Comment: @PRANDO When using double buffering, you don't need `glFlush`, since the command queue will already be flushed by `glutSwapBuffers`. This is in turn definitely needed, since it swaps the front and back buffer and this way displays what you have drawn. From your perspective `glFlush` doesn't really do anything.

Comment: @PRANDO If with coplanar surfaces you mean polygons rendered at the same depth on top of each other, this depends if depth testing is enabled (you called `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`) and if you have a context with a depth buffer (created using the `GLUT_DEPTH` flag in `glutInitDisplayMode`). If depth testing is disabled, the polygon drawn last will just be drawn on top of the previous polygon, since OpenGL, well, just draws things onto the screen.

Comment: @PRANDO When depth testing is enabled, you might get into z-fighting issues and one polygon might flicker through the other. But there are techniques to resolve these artifacts, which are actually worth their own question. But if you don't even know what depth testing is, that (or actually a more thorough OpenGL or 3d graphics learning resource) should be the first starting point.